# Query Database For Each User In Array

Tags: java, android, json

I have a facebook graph response which gets an array of *names* and *IDs*:

```
{"data":[{"id":"1402927803328937","name":"Spencer Jones"},{"id":"1402874766667901","name":"Jane Dickson"}],"}
```

I need to query my database once for each separate user returned in the first array using the *ID* from the array to check the 'status' of that user.

**My code is currently querying the database for the same ID twice instead of the two different IDs in the first array**. I must have something in the wrong place, but I can't figure it out.

```
06-13 21:08:54.081: D/FBID:(11514): 277976949048048
06-13 21:08:54.081: D/ID:(11514): 1402927803328937
06-13 21:08:54.081: D/NAME:(11514): Spencer Jones
06-13 21:08:54.631: E/JSON Parser(11514): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-13 21:08:54.631: D/JSON 1:(11514): {"message":"Products found","success":1,"products":[{"from_user":"277976949048048","them_status":"accepted","status":"pending","to_user":"1402874766667901"}]}
06-13 21:08:54.631: D/FBID:(11514): 277976949048048
06-13 21:08:54.631: D/ID:(11514): 1402874766667901
06-13 21:08:54.631: D/NAME:(11514): Jane Dickson
06-13 21:08:55.191: E/JSON Parser(11514): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-13 21:08:55.191: D/JSON 1:(11514): {"message":"Products found","success":1,"products":[{"from_user":"277976949048048","them_status":"accepted","status":"pending","to_user":"1402874766667901"}]}
```

There are JSON parsing errors in the log, but it doesn't make sense to me since it's returning all 4 variables that I need. The only issue is that it's doing the same ID twice instead of 2 different ones.

```
// getting JSON Array from facebook response
                products = FriendResponse.getJSONArray("data");

                // looping through products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbid", fbid));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                        Log.d("FBID: ", fbid);
                        Log.d("ID: ", id);

                        // getting JSON string from URL
                        JSONObject json1 = jsonParser1.makeHttpRequest(url_friend_status, "POST", params1);

                        Log.d("JSON 1: ", json1.toString());

                        products1 = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                     // looping through products1
                        for (int j = 0; j < products1.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject d = products1.getJSONObject(j);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String status = d.getString(TAG_STATUS);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);    
                    map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);    

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
                }
```

Comment: You might want to tag the question with the language you are using to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

// getting JSON Array from facebook response
                products = FriendResponse.getJSONArray("data");

```
            // looping through products
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbid", fbid));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                    Log.d("FBID: ", fbid);
                    Log.d("ID: ", id);



                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);    
                map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);    

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                productsList.add(map);
            }
```

Since the JSON File has only one array (Example: {myJSONDATA:[{}]} ) the [ ] is only one array you dont need to loop twice you should only loop once.

Comment: That would work fine for just displaying the FriendResponse, but I need to query my database for each ID in FriendResponse to find their 'status'